# Ajax success function runs only every second time

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a page where incomes and expenses can be tracked. However, once I click the `send` button on the page, ajax returns success only the first time, so the `alert(successNum)` function works only 50% of the time.

This is the **index.php** ,where the ajax call is.

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
          <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2c66dc83e7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title>Arpad Media IO</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body>
                        <h1 align=center>Budget</br><button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#budgetModal">Add entry</button></h1>
                        <table class="budget_table">
                        <tr><td><h3>Incomes</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Expenses</h3></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><table class="income_table money_table"><tr>
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `main_budget` WHERE `Type` = 'INC' ORDER BY `Date` DESC";
                        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                        $statement->execute();
                        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                        foreach($result as $row){
                            echo '<tr><td><h3 class="text text-success">+'.$row["Amount"].' Ft</h3><h5>'.$row["Description"].'</h5></td></tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr></table></td>
                        <td><table class="expense_table money_table "><tr>
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `main_budget` WHERE `Type` = 'EXP' ORDER BY `Date` DESC";
                        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                        $statement->execute();
                        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                        foreach($result as $row){
                            echo '<tr><td><h3 class="text text-danger">-'.$row["Amount"].' Ft</h3><h5>'.$row["Description"].'</h5></td></tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr></table></td>
                        </tr></table>
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `main_budget` ORDER BY `Date` DESC";
                        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                        $statement->execute();
                        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                        $TotalMoney=0;
                        foreach($result as $row){
                            if ($row["Type"]=="EXP"){
                                $row["Amount"]=$row["Amount"]*-1;
                            }
                            $TotalMoney += $row["Amount"];
                        }
                        echo '<h4 class="finalValue">Total: '.$TotalMoney.' Ft</h4>';
                        $connect=null;
                        ?>
        <div class="modal fade" id="budgetModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="budgetModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Entry</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="sendBudgetForm">
            <select class="form-control" id="budgetTypeSelect">
              <option value="INC">Income</option>
              <option value="EXP">Expense</option>
            </select>
                <input class="form-control" id="budgetName" type="text" placeholder="Title"></input>
                <input class="form-control" id="budgetValue" type="number" placeholder="Amount"></input>
                <input type="hidden" id="userName" value=<?php echo $_SESSION["UserUserName"];?>></input>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" id="sendBudget" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send"></input>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </html>
        <script>
        $('#sendBudgetForm').on('submit', function () {
        var bType = $( "#budgetTypeSelect").val();
        var bName = document.getElementById('budgetName').value;
        var bVal = document.getElementById('budgetValue').value;
        var bUser = document.getElementById('userName').value;
        $.ajax({
               url:"budgetHandler.php",
               type:"POST",
               data:{bType:bType, bName:bName, bVal:bVal, bUser:bUser},
               success:function(successNum){
                alert(successNum);
               },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                  alert('error');
              } 
              })

        });
    </script>
```

The **budgetHandler.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=budget", "root", "password");

if(isset($_POST["bVal"]))
{
  $query="INSERT INTO `main_budget` (`Author`, `Type`, `Description`, `Amount`)
  VALUES (:author, :typee, :descriptionn, :amount)";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
    array(
      ':author' => $_POST['bUser'],
      ':typee'  => $_POST['bType'],
      ':descriptionn' => $_POST['bName'],
      ':amount' => $_POST['bVal']
    )
  );
  $connect=null;
  echo "1";
}
?>
```

I've tried adding the *datatype:'text'* tag, but it didn't help.

Comment: $( "#budgetTypeSelect").val(); val() - its jquery function. is included?

Comment: `</html>` Is that intentional there?

Comment: @d-velop Yes, it is included, and the budgetHandler inserts to the database correctly.

Comment: @kerbholz The code I've inserted is not the full code of the site. There is a nav section too, and there is another php code at the start of the page, but those sections have nothing to do with my ajax problem.

Comment: It's just that you have the closing `html` tag, but not the opening tag, so there are mismatched tags in the code snippet you provided.  Perhaps including the opening tag,followed by a comment indicating that some irrelevant code has been ommitted. Or remove the closing html tag from the snippet.  This mismatch parallels another problem you *do* have with mismatched tags: a `form` tag is closed via a `div` and vice versa. Dunno if this is contributing to your errors, but it does need to be fixed. Consistent code indentation (which I fixed) helps for spotting this kind of easy-to-make mistake.

Comment: @SherylHohman I've added the irrelevant section too. Every tag seems closed, I am still confused what the problem could be.

Comment: Change the event binding to `$('#sendBudgetForm').on('submit', function (e) {` then add `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of the callback. See if it solves the problem.

Comment: Please look over the following help topics [How to create a Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and be sure to use consistent and proper code indentation.  Finally, it looks like your last edit added a line of `------` to the code which is superfluous, and would produce an error if this code block were executed.  Please `edit` again with these guidelines in mind.  All the best, I hope you find your solution.

Comment: @Zhafur After adding your suggestion, the modal didn't hide, so I've added $('#budgetModal').modal('hide'); and on a successful call a location.reload(); The code seems to be working perfectly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the event binding to **$('#sendBudgetForm').on('submit', function (e) {** then adding **e.preventDefault();** **$('#budgetModal').modal('hide');** and  adding **location.reload();** to the ajax call's success function seems to fix my error!